# Matching alghoritm in bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, bipartite

I know, this looks like school homework, but this is a real business problem.
Since I cannot write, what kind of object we are working with, I will use a bit surrealistic problem description:

There is a number of cities(a few dozens).
Each city has maximum number of missiles, that can hit it(ranging from 1 to few hundreds).

There is also a number of missiles, distributed around the world (about 1-2 thousands).
Each missile has a list of cities it can target. There can be only one city, there can be a few, or it can contains all possible cities.

Task:

Assign targets to missiles so that the maximum number of missiles can fire.

What we are doing now, is "naive-force-random" solution:

```
1. Randomly sort list of missiles
2. Pass each missile, and set it to target first city from it's list, that still can accept missile
3. Count number of of targeted missiles
4. If it's better than best solution so far, save it
5. Repeat multiple times (we can do this about 1-10 million times in reasonable time).
```

We can slightly improve results, if we start from targeting cities, that has less missiles than allowed maximum - but the rest is still a matter of randomizing and repetitions.

Physically test every solution is impossible, as there will more than > 1000! (thousand factorial) combinations.

I am looking for alghoritm, maybe some link, or literature, that can fit my problem.
This is a kind of graph theory problem, with bipartite graph - even a name of this kind of graph would be helpful in futher investigation.

We were thinking about the Hopcroft-Carp alghorithm, but it will not fit - it would be good if only one missile per city would be allowed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Feel free to correct my English.

Comment: Seems you need to find a maximal flow in graph. Build kinda bipartite graph with two layers (nodes mean cities, edges of capacity one mean missiles), but from the right one you need to add edges with capacity maximum number of missiles, that can hit it to the final node.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way is to use a genetic algorithm. If there are m missiles, a chromosome would be a vector of m values, each value being an integer in a range (0, 1,..., n). 0 is a special value that means "no target". n is a value that depends on the missile (since each missile has its own list of possible targets).

The function to maximize (chromosome fitness) is the number of non-zero values.

There is however an issue with crossing and mutation: they can generate invalid solutions (because city capacities may not be satisfied). A workaround is to apply a penalty to the fitness function.

Say we have city 1 with capacity 10 and city 2 with capacity 5. If city 1 receives 12 missiles and city 2 receives 8, we have 2 + 3 = 5 extra missiles. Remove 5*k from the fitness (k is some coefficient that will need to be chosen).

The genetic algorithm favors chromosomes with a high fitness, which means it should produce solutions that satisfy the capacity constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Hopcroft-Karp requires only minimal modifications to be able to handle this problem.

You *could* split each city into N copies, where N is the number of missiles that it can accept, so that each copy could accept just 1 missile.  Then you would be looking for a bipartite maximal bipartite matching and you could use Hopcroft-Karp.

That would greatly multiply the size of your problem, of course, and the number of solutions, since it doesn't matter which copy of a city you target with any missile, and many of the matchings your could find would end up as the same solution once you recombine the split cities.

But now that you know you could do it, imagine finding an augmenting path, starting at a free city, in the kind of solution you already have, where a city can have up to its capacity in edges.

1. An augmenting path needs to start at a free city -- that's one with less than its current edge capacity.
2. It then follows an unused edge to a missile;
3. It then follows an existing edge to a city,  The capacity of the city doesn't matter, because;
4. It then follows an unused edge to another missile, and 3-4 repeat as needed.

Now when you flip edges along the augmenting path, *only the start city* sees a change in the number of missiles that target it, so you don't need to consider city capacities in any way during the search.

The only real difference between this search and Hopcroft-Karp, is that you need to allow for paths that visit the same city (but not the same missile) multiple times.

Comment: Sounds great! I will try it later.